# How to exclude paths from being extracted when extracting an iso using xorriso

Tags: iso, mkisofs

As an example I'm trying to extract all the files from the ubuntu live iso **except** the path `/casper/filesystem.squashfs`. According to the man page:

```
       Normally  xorriso  only writes to disk files which were given as stdio:
       pseudo-drives or as log files.  But its alter ego osirrox  is  able  to
       extract  file  objects  from  ISO  images  and to create, overwrite, or
       delete file objects on disk.
       Disk file exclusions by -not_mgt, -not_leaf, -not_paths apply.
```

I can extract all paths on the iso fine using:

```
xorriso -osirrox on -indev ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso -extract / extract_dir
```

But I've been attempting to use the disk file exclusions but to no avail. I've tried different variations or `not_leaf` and `not_paths` in different orders both before and after the `-extract` action. They all extract all paths. Here's a few that I've tried.

Using `not_leaf`:

```
xorriso -osirrox on -indev ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso -not_leaf 'filesystem.squashfs' -extract / extracted_dir
xorriso -osirrox on -indev ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso -extract / extracted_dir -not_leaf 'filesystem.squashfs'
xorriso -osirrox on -indev ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso -not_mgt on -not_leaf 'filesystem.squashfs' -extract / extracted_dir
xorriso -osirrox on -indev ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso -not_mgt on -extract / extracted_dir -not_leaf 'filesystem.squashfs'
```

Using `not_paths` with reorderings as above:

```
xorriso -osirrox on -indev ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso -not_mgt on -not_paths 'casper/filesystem.squashfs' -- -extract / extracted_dir
xorriso -osirrox on -indev ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso -not_mgt on -not_paths '/casper/filesystem.squashfs' -- -extract / extracted_dir
xorriso -osirrox on -indev ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso -not_mgt on -not_paths 'extracted_dir/casper/filesystem.squashfs' -- -extract / extracted_dir
```

I would accept an answer with `not_leaf` or `not_paths`, but would prefer both. And an explanation of the logic behind how this is supposed to work (ie why am I not getting it?) would be nice.

Comment: I'd use `bsdtar` instead of `xorriso` which supports a wide variety of archive formats including most iso ones, then you can apply the same recipes to all archive formats.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I specifically asked about xorriso because I'm only wanting to extract iso files, wanting to minimize dependencies, already using xorriso, and xorriso docs suggest that what I want is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The settings `-not_leaf` and `-no_path` are for the situation of inserting
trees into the ISO image.

For the osirrox case you will have to (temporarily) reduce the content
of the tree which you want to copy as a whole out of the ISO.
Use xorriso commands `-rm` and `-rm_r` for that purpose. Note that both
have variable length parameter lists which need to be ended by "`--`".
At normal program end, there will be resistance because the changes have
not been stored to ISO. (Batch throws FAILURE, dialog would not let you
out.) Avoid this by a final command `-rollback_end`.

```
xorriso -osirrox on \
        -indev ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso \
        -rm /casper/filesystem.squashfs -- \
        -extract / extract_dir \
        -rollback_end
```

Another problem might be the read-only directory permissions inside
Ubuntu ISOs. They hamper manipulation after extraction. Inside the
ISO this can be changed by a `-find` command like in this run:

```
xorriso -osirrox on \
        -indev ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso \
        -rm /casper/filesystem.squashfs -- \
        -find / -type d -exec chmod u+w -- \
        -extract / extract_dir \
        -rollback_end
```

Keep in mind that all changes to the ISO need to be done before the `-extract` command. Sequence matters.

Comment: Am I reading the man page incorrectly as quoted above then? And if I am, what does "Disk file exclusions by -not_mgt, -not_leaf, -not_paths apply." mean in the context of osirrox?

Comment: You are right. The promise of the man page is not fulfilled.
Only the absolute path of disk directory "extract_dir" is currently
submitted to the exclusion test. All deeper files of the tree do not
get tested. This is obviously a bug.

Comment: Please report the bug to bug-xorriso@gnu.org . A link to this stackexchange page will suffice.